# Python search for patterns in all lines, export only lines with results

Tags: python, regex

I would like to search for strings that match a pattern in a text file and export only the matched strings

```
k=''
regex = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{8}')

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace(',', '')
        line = line.replace('.', '')
        k = regex.findall(line)
        #k.append(line)
    if not k=='':
        position=True
    else:
        position=False
    if position==True:
        print(k)
```

Somehow my code doesn't work, it always returns the following output:

```
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] ['AI13933231'] [] [] [] [] []
```

I want the output to contain only the matched strings. Thank you!

Comment: Please indent your code with 4 spaces on each line to show it as code - you have put your code in a blockqoute with ` > `

Comment: Can you please describe your regex? The regex so far looks like "two letters followed by eight digits". And where is your sample text file? I have suggested an edit, but can you please reformat your indenting so your code actually works and is neat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why there are empty array literals `[]` is because this line actually exists, but is either empty (containing just `\n`) or does not match the regex `'[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{8}'`. And please note that `regex.findall(line)` returns an list, so if the regex did not find any that matches, it is an empty list.

Your main error happened in this section: `if not k=='':`. Note `k` is an list.

Consider this code:

```
import re

k=''
regex = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{8}')

with open("omg.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace(',', '')
        line = line.replace('.', '')
        k = regex.findall(line)
        #k.append(line)

        position = False        
        if str(k) != '[]': # The `[]` is just the string representation of an empty array
            position=True
            print(k)
        else:
            position=False
```

Given the file (Text after # are ignored, not part of the file)

```
AZ23153133
# Empty line
AB12355342
gz # No match
XY93312344
```

The output would be

```
['AZ23153133']
['AB12355342']
['XY93312344']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I kept forgetting that findall returns a list!